# Error con tipo word

Tags: genexus

Trabajo con GeneXus v17 / U11 y generador java.

Intentamos hacer un reporte que el texto se cargue desde un archivo word.
En pricipio, el error que nos da es sobre el 'gxoffice2.dll' y el '.jar' que ya esta copiado y registrado.
La duda es que si aun no teniendo Office en la PC a generar, es posible hacer esto?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Procura incluir el error completo (no un resumen tuyo) y provee detalles para que las personas no tengan que adivinar. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.